# FCK editor Problem

Tags: php, fckeditor

FCK EDITOR-in my php website i am using FCK editor.But Sometimes when i am using editing purpose the content not to be seemed in the fck editor.It will show a gray color only.Contant is not viewved.Whats the reason for that?

Comment: FCK is out of date you should be using CKEditor. http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: @Dagon: That might not be an easy option if custom plugins are involved.

Comment: i've used FCKeditor extensively and never seen it show a gray area instead of editable contents. maybe you could supply some code to show how you set it up?

Answer (score 2):

I think did you make changes in fckconfig.js file, so first you have to put default fckconfig.js file than check it again.